# ORDER BY votes_up - votes_down

Tags: php

I've 2 rows in a table, one is called votes_up and the other is called votes_down.

I want to create a new page where all most rated contents are displayed. Both rows are positive numbers so I need to `-` them but I've already tried to do that. Already created a new row called `countvotes` But I cannot insert `-1` or `+1` into database some how

```
$q_13 = "UPDATE post SET votes_up = $votes_up AND votecount = '+1' WHERE id = $id";
```

Comment: why not just `votes_up = votes_up-1` and `votes_down = votes_down-1`?

Comment: To increase a column by +1 you need to do something like `SET votes_up = votes_up +1` and if you have a variable then do `SET votes_up = $votes_up +1` the same applies to doing `-1`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Done, sorry thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create a new column.

```
SELECT (votes_up - votes_down) AS totalVotes FROM post ORDER BY totalVotes DESC
```

This query gives you post with vote order.

Answer (score 1):

```
$q_13 = "
UPDATE post
 SET votes_up = $votes_up,
votecount = votecount+1 
WHERE id = $id";
```

Rather than using a variable to increment the value, I am taking the field and adding it by one for the update.

Comment: Code-only answers are not as helpful.  Explain what you are doing, so people can better understand.

Comment: Remvove the `AND` then replace with a comma.

Comment: can't believe I didn't catch that! how embarrassing!

Answer (score 1):

Based on you SQL you can do this

```
$q_13 = "UPDATE post SET votes_up = $votes_up, votecount = votecount +1 WHERE id = $id";
```

However if you want to select from the DB based on a diference

```
$q_13 = "SELECT id, (vote_up - votes_down) as voteCount FROM postORDER BY voteCount
```

Comment: Remvove the `AND` then replace with a comma.

Comment: -1 See my comment above which you haven't done. `AND` is used when querying using a `WHERE` clause that meets a certain criteria. I.e.: `WHERE column_1=x AND column_2=y`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yup, I should have checked my typing, dunno what I was thinking.  I'm editing it now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change you query to

```
 $q_13 = "UPDATE post 
          SET 
         votes_up = $votes_up, 
         votecount = votecount+1 

         WHERE 

         id = $id";
```